# Increase the time of the character being at the peak of the jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics

I am working on a character controller for a 2d-platformer I am using Unity3D to implement it using my own physics (not the standard physics and the RigidBody2D component), anyway I finished it mostly but the problem is the jump, it is satisfying but I want the character to stay a little bit longer in the air when it reaches the peak of the jump, but without using a timer or so, what I mean by that, I want the character to raise slower when it gets close to the jump peak, so the jump curve gets wider.

The way I handle the velocity and movement is so:
- I have a Vector2 velocity that represent the current velocity, it is set each frame depending on the current state of the character(Walking, Running, Idle,...)
- I have a float gravity which is a fixed float representing the gravity
- When the player jumps, I set its velocity.y to jumpVelocity and each frame, I subtract (gravity * Time.DeltaTime) from it.

The jump curve I get:

[image]

The jump curve I want:

[image]

Anyway easy way (Changing a factor or adding a variable or so) to achieve that without rewriting 50% of my code? 
Thanks in advance :)

With (gravity*time^2) as mentioned in the comments:

[image]

Comment: Try decreasing both `gravity` and `jumpVelocity`

Comment: From a physics standpoint couldn't you just increase the horizontal velocity to achieve this goal?

Comment: @Ruzihm actually decreasing only the gravity is enough to achieve that curve but can't change it, the gravity in my code is calculated from 2 other variables which are maxJumpHeight and timeToJumpApex....

Comment: @plum0 From a physics perspective: you're right, from a game perspective: no! the horizontal velocity here is the air movement speed of the player, which just fits the game and cannot be changed simply

Comment: It sounds like what you really need to do then is to subtract less from your velocity.y as you approach your peak jump. This means that as velocity.y approaches 0, you want to decrease less. Currently, you have a linear deceleration. What you need is a parabolic deceleration. (Think derivatives?)

I would try messing with something along the lines of decrementing (gravity*time^2)/x where x is some constant used to achieve the same height as it is currently

Comment: (gravity*time^2) is exactly what I thought about, is the variable x related in anyway to the horrible curve I got? :) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TjTCFAUdI_aHkgbWFFZMIjcLYEKo444u/view?usp=sharing @plum0

Comment: @MuhammadNihad you should edit the question to include your code because `gravity` being "calculated from 2 other variables" doesn't provide enough information to allow someone to answer the question.  It's impossible to tell what the variables do by just looking at the names. But if you want more air time without changing the jump height, a good starting point might be increasing `timeToJumpApex`.

Comment: @MuhammadNihad I can not view files in side of google drive (work policy). If possible could you post the image like you did other two in the original post, stating the new formula you tried as well?

Perhaps I didn't fully think through the effects of that equation completely. At a guess I can only assume it looks like [this](https://www.analyzemath.com/Graphing/cubic_graph_1.gif)

Comment: @MuhammadNihad hmmmm. It looks like the latter half of that is exactly the type of curve you were looking for (to some scale haha). Now why is the curve the same before the peak...  It isn't reducing enough velocity up until the peak now. This could be because the x set was too high for the lower numbers of time. (if time is 1 second, then you are subtracting 1/x of gravity). This means that if x is too high then your earlier times will not be effected as much as the latter half. Could we scale the numerator of the fraction by a constant as well? Something like `(gravity*(c*time)^2)/x`?

Comment: I'm also no wiz when it comes to this type of math/thinking. It could be that we need the opposite case (sqrt of time), but I would just play around with ratios and values until you get a curve that somewhat resembles what you want :)

Comment: I solved the problem, thanks a lot guys :) problems of this kind are hard to solve because they are related to game feel more than maths and real world physics so usually normal physics equations don't solve theme, instead, one should try to balance variables and tweak values in a way that doesn't affect other things until it feels right, thanks again :)

Comment: @MuhammadNihad Well please post a solution and accept it as the answer. I'm curious to know what you did to get your desired curve, even though I know nothing about unity or game physics.

Comment: @plum0 I did that, I don't think it will help you a lot though.

Answer (score 1):

The time until reaching the peak is computed by setting

```
jumpVelocity - time * gravity = 0,
```

i.e.

```
time = jumpVelocity / gravity.
```

If you want your character to stay in the air for a longer time, you can increase the 
 `jumpVelocity` or decrease the `gravity`.

However, this also leads to higher jumps.

The height of the jump is (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_motion#Equations_of_kinematics)

```
height = jumpVelocity * time - gravity/2 * time^2.       (*)
```

With time from above, you get

```
height = jumpVelocity^2 / (2*gravity),
```

which with the time above yields

```
time = 2*height / jumpVelocity.       (**)
```

Thus, to e.g. jump twice as long while keeping the height constant, you have to multiply `jumpVelocity` by 0.5 due to (**) and `gravity` by 0.25 due to (*).

Comment: Owww thanks for the equations, they helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the ratio of horizontal and vertical velocity. So you could either leave gravity and jump velocity untouched and increase the horizontal velocity, or decrease both gravity and jumping velocity (proportionally).

Comment: unfortunately non of the 2 options are possible:  the horizontal velocity here is the air movement speed of the player, which just fits the game and cannot be changed simply, the vertical velocity and the gravity on the other hand are calculated from other variables: maxJumpHeight and timeToJumpApex, so cannot be changed to....

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution that I implemented after changing the code a little bit...
expanding on the method of Sebastian Lague (An amazing youtuber), it is possible now to scale the curve horizontally (using `timeToJumpApex` variable) and vertically (using `maxJumpHeight` variable):

```
gravity = -(2 * maxJumpHeight) / Mathf.Pow(timeToJumpApex, 2);
maxJumpVelocity = Mathf.Abs(gravity) * timeToJumpApex;
```

This method will also calculate the gravity for you...
Anyway my jump still doesn't feel that good yet, but that is not related to maths and physics equations nor to implementation problems, but as it turned out this curve is not the best one for a platformer jump...

**Edit:** The way I apply gravity to velocity didn't change, so:

```
velocity += (gravity * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: What was the equation before you changed it? It's hard to tell exactly what you did to fix the problem because the code that caused the problem isn't included in the question.